ImplicitRegion and RegionPlot
Here is a very simple example of ImplicitRegion:
region=ImplicitRegion[-0.5 <= x <= 0.5 && -1 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];

I tried to draw its domain with RegionPlot and got a result as below.
RegionPlot[region, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 1000]


The result does not include 4 corners, and neitherPerformanceGoal nor PlotPoints  improve.
Element[{0.5, 1}, region] (* True *)
RegionMeasure[region] (* 2. *)

are as expected and another command works like this.
RegionPlot[True, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -1, 1}]


I found some related questions and no helpful solution.
I want to define more complicated regions with ImplicitRegion for later application.

Somehow this works:  region = ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] <= 1/2 && Abs[y] <= 1, {x, y}].

@David, your definition gives a correct answer. I wonder why my definition is not adequate.

@cvgmt , I could not find the question you mentioned and your answer is what I want.
